# Coroutines CancellationException expected behaviour

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

So based on Kotlin introduction to coroutines, in [*Cancellation and Timeouts -> Run non-cancellable block*](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/cancellation-and-timeouts.html) I found following explanation: `Any attempt to use a suspending function in the finally block [...] causes CancellationException` but when running:

```
fun runPlayground() = runBlocking {
    val job = launch {
        try {
            repeat(1000) { i ->
                Log.d("XXX", "job: I'm sleeping $i ...")
                delay(500L)
            }
        } finally {
            doWorld() // logs "World" after 1s delay
            delay(2000L)
            Log.d("XXX", "job: I'm running finally")
        }
    }
    delay(1300L) // delay a bit
    Log.d("XXX", "main: I'm tired of waiting!")
    job.cancelAndJoin() // cancels the job and waits for its completion
    Log.d("XXX", "main: Now I can quit.")
}
```

results in logging:

```
D/XXX: job: I'm sleeping 0 ...
D/XXX: job: I'm sleeping 1 ...
D/XXX: job: I'm sleeping 2 ...
D/XXX: main: I'm tired of waiting!
D/XXX: main: Now I can quit.
```

Finally block is not executed probably due to running suspend functions there, but I would expect getting `CancellationException` there as I run that code from:

```
try {
    runPlayground()
} catch (e: CancellationException)  {
    Log.d("XXX", e.message)
}
```

Is the exception handled internally in the coroutines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception is thrown from `doWorld()` and from that point it escapes the coroutine block and gets silently swallowed because you haven't installed any unhandled [exception handler](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-coroutine-exception-handler/). The dispatcher it was running on doesn't crash due to that exception.

If you study the documentation under the above link, you'll learn that the exception is silently swallowed only because it's a `CancelationException`. Any other exception would at least show up in the same manner that an unhandled exception appears in a Java thread, for example:

```
fun main() = runBlocking {
    launch(Job()) {
        throw Exception("I failed")
    }.join()
    println("runBlocking done")
}
```

This prints

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Exception: I failed
    at org.mtopol.TestingKt$main$1$1.invokeSuspend(testing.kt:8)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(Dispatched.kt:241)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.EventLoopImplBase.processNextEvent(EventLoop.common.kt:270)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BlockingCoroutine.joinBlocking(Builders.kt:79)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking(Builders.kt:54)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking(Unknown Source)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking$default(Builders.kt:36)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking$default(Unknown Source)
    at org.mtopol.TestingKt.main(testing.kt:6)
    at org.mtopol.TestingKt.main(testing.kt)

runBlocking done
```

Note especially that the `main` thread didn't actually die: it went on to print the line `runBlocking done`. Kotlin just reuses the installed `currentThread().uncaughtExceptionHandler()` to log coroutine failures.

---

When I went to test code similar to above, but with an installed `CoroutineExceptionHandler`, I found some problems:

1. An exception handler in a child coroutine is ignored. This seems to be by design, but it's not documented.
2. `runBlocking` seems to have a bug and, even if you install a handler to it, it won't run.

I created an [issue](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/1746) about this.

Comment: Is it anyway possible to catch it somehow? From what I've noticed, after adding EH to launch or runBlocking I still get no log there for CancellationException, when trowing any other RuntimeException I'm ending with crash of the app (running it in onCreate of Android app). I tried experimenting with the contexts' but still same results.

Comment: `CoroutineExceptionHandler` doesn't actually handle the exception, it only observes it. By that time the coroutine has already crashed. If you want to gracefully handle coroutine exceptions, you must have a `try-catch` directly inside the coroutine builder block (the coroutine's top level).

Comment: But when having EH that simply logs the exception message, can I expect him to do that? That is not happening in my case. Right now EH seems doing nothing, it is not called with the exception that is later crashing / handled by outer try catch.

Comment: btw. I know maybe that use case is not even sth real, but I am experimenting and found that interesting to investigate/understand more deeply.

Comment: I suggest you study the documentation on `CoroutineExceptionHandler`, it specifies precisely what and when is being handled and/or reported.